# Why isn't SharedPreferences saving my string?

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, sharedpreferences

I have an ArrayList that I'm writing out as a string:

```
blastScores  = new ArrayList<String>();
blastScores.add("Hello");
blastScores.add("Yo");
prefs.edit().putString(CaptureActivity.BLAST_SCORES, blastScores.toString());
```

Whenever I read it in, it is always null:

```
    String blastScoresString = prefs.getString(CaptureActivity.BLAST_SCORES, null);
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you done a `commit()` on the `SharedPreferences.Editor` object?